# Xamarin attach debugger to android slow

Tags: android, debugging, xamarin

I'm going crazy over this.

I am developing a Xamarin App, and when I am in the COmpany debugging is fast and works as expected. If i go home and worke in my own network on the same Laptop, my debugger takes ages to load Assemblys.

I have a lot of Assemblies so it takes allmost 20 minutest to atach to the debugger.
If I only deploy and run the app that works fine an is as fast as you would expect, debugging though, holds for round about 30seconds for each assemblyto load,

```
Loaded assembly: Xamarin.Android.ReactiveStreams.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Xamarin.Android.ReactiveX.RxJava.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Xamarin.AndroidX.Activity.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Xamarin.AndroidX.Annotation.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Xamarin.AndroidX.Annotation.Experimental.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Xamarin.AndroidX.AppCompat.AppCompatResources.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Xamarin.AndroidX.AppCompat.dll [External]
```

so the part above, took 3 and a half minutes to load, i thought this might be a networ setup issue on my site, so I threw out all the company controlled Networksettings and rebooted, but no, improvements where made here. I know that adb and devenv communicate over localhost, this communication seems unaffected.

Fyi: My network speed at home is faster down, as at the company and a tat slower or even on upstream.

So....

If someone did experience anything similar, or has some hints for me, help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You can use Microsoft (was Sysinternals) Process Monitor to get more information what your application does (what files and registry keys have been accessed). This possible could provide you some clue, what is happening during the slow assembly loading such as like trying to load assembly from some very slow network shares.

Comment: thanks for the input, i see the same error in the Process Monitor the pdb file cannot be found. and it isnt there but it should be there ind if its not there it should be loaded frome the nuget server, or be generated localy.

Comment: You can  recheck to see if any other apps are enabled or other devices are using your network.